# Use less -S and less in alias

Tags: bash, alias, less-unix

I always use less -S instead of less, so I create an alias `less="less -S"`.

But sometimes, I want to use less without -S. I tried something like `les=less`, but of course, it doesn't work because `les` calls the other alias `less -S`.

Is there a solution?

(Note: I don't want to just rename my less alias because when other people use my computer they always use less without -S and I find the output hard to read for some huge files.)

Comment: To execute a command without using defined aliases start it with backslash `\less` or if you want your alias `alias les='\less'`

Comment: ^^ or use `command less` e.g. `command less filename` or `some_cmd | command less`. With your case, you can use `alias les='command less'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the second alias so that it contains the full path to the `less` executable:

```
alias les='/usr/bin/less'
```

Alternatively, use a backslash to prevent alias expansion:

```
alias les='\less'
```